# advice on tidying up php that is checking DB entry & changing select dropdown 'selected'

Tags: php, database, variables, select, dropdown

I am looking for advice and the best way to tidy up the following php code.

I am checking the database for **$this->item->values['']** and changing a select dropdown's **selected="selected"** accordingly.

How can this be made cleaner/simpler?

```
<?php
  $minbedroomsCheck = '';
  if ( $this->item->values['min-bedrooms'] < '0' ) {
      $minbedroomsCheck = 'selected="selected"';
  }
  $minbedroomsanyCheck = '';
  if ( $this->item->values['min-bedrooms'] == '0' ) {
      $minbedroomsanyCheck = 'selected="selected"';
  }
  $minbedrooms1Check = '';
  if ( $this->item->values['min-bedrooms'] == '1' ) {
      $minbedrooms1Check = 'selected="selected"';
  }
  $minbedrooms2Check = '';
  if ( $this->item->values['min-bedrooms'] == '2' ) {
      $minbedrooms2Check = 'selected="selected"';
  }
  $minbedrooms3Check = '';
  if ( $this->item->values['min-bedrooms'] == '3' ) {
      $minbedrooms3Check = 'selected="selected"';
  }
  $minbedrooms4Check = '';
  if ( $this->item->values['min-bedrooms'] == '4' ) {
      $minbedrooms4Check = 'selected="selected"';
  }
  $minbedrooms5Check = '';
  if ( $this->item->values['min-bedrooms'] == '5' ) {
      $minbedrooms5Check = 'selected="selected"';
  }
?>
<select id="min-bedrooms" name="min-bedrooms" class="profile-select">
  <option value="" <?= $minbedroomsCheck ?>>Min Bedrooms</option>
  <option value="0" <?= $minbedroomsanyCheck ?>>Any</option>
  <option value="1" <?= $minbedrooms1Check ?>>1+</option>
  <option value="2" <?= $minbedrooms2Check ?>>2+</option>
  <option value="3" <?= $minbedrooms3Check ?>>3+</option>
  <option value="4" <?= $minbedrooms4Check ?>>4+</option>
  <option value="5" <?= $minbedrooms5Check ?>>5+</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Isn't it a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below,

1. First store the **min-bedrooms count** in database
2. Then store the **min-bedrooms selected** value in database,

The retrieve the ***min-bedrooms*** count and ***min-bedrooms selected*** value and do a for loop as below

```
<?php 
$min_bedrooms = 6; // this should be stored in database
$min_bedrooms_selected = 4; //$this->item->values['min-bedrooms']
?>

<select class="profile-select" name="min-bedrooms" id="min-bedrooms">
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < $min_bedrooms; $i++){ ?>
    <?php if($i == $min_bedrooms_selected){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>" selected="selected"> <?php echo $i;?></option>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you... maybe I should have added that the form is initially empty. when making the choices, that choice is added to the database table as: "min-bedrooms":"2"- so this is what I want to pull back next time they go to that view, by checking the database - hence, the if statement on the $this->item->values['min-bedrooms'] == '2'

Comment: @user991830 Yes exactly...Also you should store the **min bedrooms amount** allowed.